# Entity Framework c# (возвращается null для столбца)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему при  наследовании по ключу в EF, значение Company_Id всегда возвращает null? Остальные значения Department_Id и Subdivision_Id значение возвращают.

```
public string getFullDepartmentByDepId(int _depId)
    {
        var _tree = _context?.StruktureTree.Include(d=>d.Department).Where(c => c.Subdisvision_Id == _depId)?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (_tree != null)
        {
            string _fullDep = string.Format("{0}>{1}>{2}", _tree?.Company?.NameDep, _tree?.Department?.NameDep, _tree?.Subdisvision?.NameDep);
            return _fullDep;
        }
        return "отдел не найден";
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Добавил

```
.Include(d=>d.Department)
         .Include(c=>c.Company)
         .Include(c => c.Subdisvision)
```

Не загружались данные из-за Lazy Load.